# Keep input disabled until correct option is selected in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the 'date' input to be disabled until the 'Deadline' option is selected. I have tried the following but it is not working. Any Suggestions?

**CODE**

```
<Select>
  <option onselect="document.getElementById('deadline').disabled = false;">Deadline date</option>
  <option>Monthly</option>
</Select>

<input id="deadline" type="date" disabled>
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I have edited the code kindly review it

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem, but you're missing your closing quotes on the `onselect=`

Comment: Please, verify your html first. You are missing some closing quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should to it:

```js
function validate() {

  var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  var selectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var input = document.getElementById('date');
  
  if (selectedOption == "enabled") {
    input.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    input.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" onchange="validate()">
  <option value="disabled">Pick something</option>
  <option value="enabled">Deadline date</option>
  <option value="disabled">Monthly</option>
</select>

<input type="date" id="date" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to attach an event handler to the `change` event on your select, then check its value with `this.value`.

Finally, set the `disabled` attribute of your input to `true` or `false` accordingly.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('deadline').disabled = this.value != 'Deadline date';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Deadline date</option>
  <option>Monthly</option>
</select>

<input id="deadline" type="date" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

At `dropdown` change event you can add or remove `attribute` like this with your match condition.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Deadline date')
    $('#inpTest').removeAttr('disabled');
  else
    $('#inpTest').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select>
 <option>---select---</option>
  <option>Deadline date</option>
  <option>Monthly</option>
</Select>

<input type="date" disabled="disabled" id='inpTest'>
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is event on **<`option`>** is not trigger. please check below code.

```
<select id="selectedOption" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option>select</option>
  <option>Deadline date</option>
  <option>Monthly</option>
</select>

<input id="deadline" type="date" disabled>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("selectedOption").value == "Deadline date") {
        document.getElementById("deadline").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("deadline").disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

hope it help you.